# AngularJs - Syncing view when processing data is required on render or model updates with OO approach

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, if you are using a object oriented approach, How do you update your views when an object instance changes certain data?

Let imagine we have this "User class":

```
function UserFactory(){

    User(name, lastName){
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    User.prototype.setName = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    User.prototype.setLastName = function(LastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    User.prototype.getFullName = function(){
        return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    return User;
}

angular.module('UserModule',[])
       .factory('UserFactory', UserFactory);
```

And our controller for the profile page looks like this:

```
/**
 *
 *  The logic for controlling the object is defined in the class
 *
 */

var MyProfileCtrl = function($scope, UserFactory){

    var user = new UserFactory("name", "second name");

    $scope.user = user;
}


angular.module('App.Profile',['UserModule'])
       .controller('MyProfile', MyProfileCtrl);
```

Ok, and now my view will show things by accessing the properties and methods of the object:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Name</p>
        <input ng-model="user.name">
    </div>

        <div>
        <p>Last Name</p>
        <input ng-model="user.lastName">
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Full Name</p>
        <p>{{user.getFullName()}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Due to getFullName returns a string (primitive value), updates into the name and lastName will not be reflected into the "Full Name" print. How do you deal with this issues?

I have been always using plain javascript data for angularjs (meaning basic structures {name: "xxx", lastName: "zzz"} and putting into the view:

```
<div>
    <p>Full Name</p>
    <p>{{user.name}} - {{user.lastName}} </p>
</div>
```

In this way I can keep the UI in sync. I know I can use **$watch** but it does smell a little bit. Despite reading all the time performance issues when using those.

So What happens when what you want to achieve requires more processing that a simple concatenation?

The whole issue that Im trying to figure out is, How do you manage pre-processing of data, which can be triggered when model changes, keeping the UI in sync? Is object oriented a bad approach? Do you use services to transform the data to what the UI really needs?

If this question goes into another section please let me know to re-postit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Due to getFullName returns a string (primitive value), updates into the name and lastName will not be reflected into the "Full Name" print.

Yes, it will. Why wouldn't it? But I fail to see the point of the setter in User, since they're not used anywhere.

> How do you manage pre-processing of data, which can be triggered when model changes, keeping the UI in sync?

You use what you have used above: a function returning the computed value and called from the view. Or, if the function is too complex and would cause performance problems if called at each digest loop, you call it every time one of its inputs change, and store the result in the scope.

To detect the changes in the inputs, and call a function accordingly, you have several choices:

- use ng-change on the input fields
- use ngModelOptions with `getterSetter` = true
- use a watch

Comment: Yes, setName and setLastName were there but I did not use them. It was planning to use it somewhere but I change the example to sth simpler, so actually I dont need those anymore. Sorry about those.

Comment: Okay, all the confusion I had was because of the get and setters https://jsbin.com/hagoru/edit?html,js,output